# how to: load drawable icon with app names in android listview

Tags: android

I was wondering how i may get this to load the drawables or icons from the applications along with its app name and activity. I looked upon many examples available already but had no idea how to implement them into this one here. if anyone can guide me, it would be great.

```
  public void loadApps() {
       final Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
       final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

       int i=0;
       int j=0;
       String tmpNick="";

        if(pkg.Name.size()!=0 ) {pkg.Name.clear(); pkg.Activity.clear(); pkg.Nick.clear();}


       switch(checkedRadioButton) {
       case 0:
                // LAUCHABLES VARIANT OF LOAD APPS


                for(i=0; i<pkgExtra.Name.size(); i++  ) 
                {
                    pkg.Name.add(pkgExtra.Name.get(i));
                    pkg.Nick.add(pkgExtra.Nick.get(i));
                    pkg.Activity.add(pkgExtra.Activity.get(i));
                }

                main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                final List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

                for(ResolveInfo launchable : launchables) 
                {                   
                    if (ItemNumInHide(launchable.activityInfo.name)==-1) 
                    {
                        pkg.Name.add(launchable.activityInfo.packageName);
                        pkg.Activity.add(launchable.activityInfo.name);
                        pkg.Nick.add(launchable.activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                    }


                }

        break;
        case 1:

                final List<ResolveInfo> launchables2=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
                )
                int length=0;
                for(ResolveInfo launchable : launchables2) 
                {
                    String[] tmpSplit = new String[10];


                    //acInfo=launchable.activityInfo; 

                    tmpSplit=launchable.activityInfo.name.split("\\.");
                    length=tmpSplit.length;

                    pkg.Name.add(launchable.activityInfo.packageName);
                    pkg.Activity.add(launchable.activityInfo.name);
                    tmpNick="";
                    tmpNick=tmpSplit[1];
                    for(j=2; j<length; j++) {
                        tmpNick=tmpNick + ":" + tmpSplit[j];
                    }

                    pkg.Nick.add(tmpNick);
                    //pkg.Nick.add(tmpSplit[length-2]+ ":" +tmpSplit[length-1]);
                }


        break;
        case 2:


            //final List<ResolveInfo> launchables3=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);


           // pkg.last=pkgExtra.Name.size()-1;
            for(i=0; i<pkgExtra.Name.size(); i++  ) 
            {

                //tmpSplit=acInfo.name.split("\\.");
                //    length=tmpSplit.length;

                pkg.Name.add(pkgExtra.Name.get(i));
                pkg.Nick.add(pkgExtra.Nick.get(i));
                pkg.Activity.add(pkgExtra.Activity.get(i));
            }

       break;
        case 3:



            //pkg.last=pkgHide.Name.size()-1;
            for(i=0; i<pkgHide.Name.size(); i++  ) 
            {

                //tmpSplit=acInfo.name.split("\\.");
                //    length=tmpSplit.length;

                pkg.Name.add(pkgHide.Name.get(i));
                pkg.Nick.add(pkgHide.Nick.get(i));
                pkg.Activity.add(pkgHide.Activity.get(i));
            }

       break;
       }
       pkg.Name.add(app_package_name+".Menu" );
       pkg.Nick.add(" Menu-Launcher");
       pkg.Activity.add(app_package_name+".Menu");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

On [Android Developers site / AsyncTaskLoader.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) there is a complete example that loads apps and displays them on a `ListView`.

If that's not enough, I have created a project out of it here: [AsyncTaskLoader](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-where-is-my-memory/tree/master/AsyncTaskLoader) with a couple modifications to run on Android 2.x.